# How can I extract only one datatype values from a mixed datatype array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, element, custom-data-type

I am having 4 different datatypes in my array list. These are specific to my application(not common data types)
Say for example Array abc has contain 10 values with
Datatype1 - 4 values,
Datatype2 - 2 values,
Datatype3 - 2 values,
Datatype4 - 2 values.
?
I need to extract Datatype1 alone(i.e 4 values). How can I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`OfType<TResult>()` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1) to filter your `ArrayList` based on a specific type.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var arrayList = new ArrayList();
        arrayList.Add(new Type1());
        arrayList.Add(new Type2());
        arrayList.Add(new Type3());
        arrayList.Add(new Type1());
        arrayList.Add(new Type2());
        arrayList.Add(new Type3());
        arrayList.Add(new Type1());
        arrayList.Add(new Type2());
        arrayList.Add(new Type3());
        arrayList.Add(new Type1());
        arrayList.Add(new Type2());
        arrayList.Add(new Type3());
        arrayList.Add(new Type1());
        arrayList.Add(new Type2());
        arrayList.Add(new Type3());
        arrayList.Add(new Type1());
        arrayList.Add(new Type2());
        arrayList.Add(new Type3());
        
        foreach (Type1 t in arrayList.OfType<Type1>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public class Type1
{
    
}

public class Type2
{
}

public class Type3
{
}
```

I'm assuming based on the language in your question that you're using an `ArrayList`, but this extension method will work on anything that implements `IEnumerable`. So this will work even if you're using an `object[]` or a `List<object>`...

That said, if you're actually using the [`ArrayList` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netcore-3.1) then you might want to check out the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) as Microsoft does not recommend that you use that class.

> We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic `List<T>` class. The ArrayList class is designed to hold heterogeneous collections of objects. However, it does not always offer the best performance. Instead, we recommend the following:
>
> For a heterogeneous collection of objects, use the `List<Object>` (in C#) or List(Of Object) (in Visual Basic) type.
>
> For a homogeneous collection of objects, use the `List<T>` class.
> See Performance Considerations in the `List<T>` reference topic for a discussion of the relative performance of these classes. See Non-generic collections shouldn't be used on GitHub for general information on the use of generic instead of non-generic collection types.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. Nope am using an Array[] not an arraylist. However this will works for me. But my intention on asking this question is anyway to do this without looping every element? since looping elements consumes more time

Comment: Can we use any method like array.cast<datatype1>().Any()

Comment: `Cast<datatype1>()` will throw an `InvalidCastException` if any of the objects in the array cannot be cast to `datatype1`. And `Any()` will just return `true` or `false` indicating if there are any items in the `IEnumerable`... it won't get you every item of type `datatype1` in the `array`, which is what your question seemed to be. I'm afraid that if what you have is an `Array` or an `object[]` then there isn't any way to get all elements of type `datatype1` without iterating the entire array.